# nginx reverse proxy + docker spring war application

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, java, docker, springframework

I have a nginx reverse proxy set up with this configuration:

```
location /auth {
   proxy_pass http://example.com:8083;
}

location /blog {
   proxy_pass http://example.com:8082;
}
```

The `blog` docker container is an angular website running on a `nginx:1.10-alpine` image on port `8082` and it works well.

The `auth` docker container is a spring-boot war application running on a `java:8-jre-alpine` image on port `8086`. Unfortunately, this `proxy_pass` mapping does not work.

Am I missing something? Do I need a special nginx setup for a java application?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the `/` after the `port number`. Here is the correct configuration:

```
location /auth {
   proxy_pass http://example.com:8083/; // slash is important
}

location /blog {
   proxy_pass http://example.com:8082;
}
```